# Storing Database Results in Local Storage to increase load times?

Tags: database, firebase, local-storage

I have a query about database design. I’m creating an app that is going to fetch data from a database about certain landmarks near the user. The app has a very high loyalty rate so the same users return often, and frequently query the database for the same items.

The items in the database will not change - they are all geographical features, and as such data won’t change. For the database we’re currently using firebase, which for all its benefits, seems to be coming in quite expensive for the number of queries we’re getting. We’re looking at ways to reduce the query load on the database.

One solution is each time a user makes a database request, the result is copied to local storage. The function then checks that the entry is stored in local storage first, and only if it’s not found sends a database query.

This sounds like it works fine in practice, however I’ve never heard of anyone else doing this, and so I wanted to get the opinion of the community at large. Is this a good way to reduce database load (and also loading times), or has anyone else got any other suggestions?

Comment: While I like the question, I am going out on a limb and say it's far too broad to be answered as is. Saying it's quite expensive is only relative to what you think is expensive. I may think that $100 for 10,000 queries is 'cheap' while you may think its 'expensive'. That then leads to the database design and coding; you could have over-denormalized (!) your structure to the point of causing excessive database hits. OR it may not be denormalized properly causing you to have to read in large chunks of data to get to a subset. So again, good question but without code and structures, unaswerable.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said if you're using Realtime Database or Firestore, but the client SDKs for both of those databases automatically cache and persist data to local storage that's read from the database.  The local cache will be used when the data hasn't changed on the server, and you won't be billed for any read operations when using cached data.  You don't really need to add your own local cache, unless you need to do something with that data that can't already be done by the client SDK.

This is all documented.  For example, for [Android using Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-offline-behavior).   [And for Firestore clients](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence).

Answer (score 0):

Adding the results of a query into the local storage is not a good idea:

1- Local storage is for some limited purposes

2- Local storage is not supported by all browsers(even not all versions)

3- Local storage is limited to 5MB across all major browsers

Removing loads on DB by adding data into the local storage is not a good idea. There are some other solution for that. You can add a no sql database which is much faster in between your app and your relational DB. You can use caching at you server side app and instead of fetching data from DB you can fetch them from memory.

If you choose cache then you have to choose a correct strategy in terms of invalidation and of choosing the correct cache:

**correct cache:** 
In memory cache (heap memory) choose this one if you have only one server in each region
Distributed Cache (in memory on another server like AWS Memcached or Redis )
etc ...

**effective invalidation:**
is your data invalidate every couple of days ? or every couple of hours? 
from what you wrote in the question it seems that data are not changed frequently, so you can put item in your cache for long time.